# How to find request payload source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, request

I want to get 1 thing from request payload looking in chrome devtools, but I don't know how to find the source of it, how it's made.

Can i somehow find it?

Comment: Look in Network tab for `Origin` and `Referer` headers. There is no info from what file and line this request was made

Comment: In Origin and referrer there is only the web adress im actually on. 
I looked into initiators tab and there is like 30 initiators. Together in these files are like 100k lines of "hidden" code. "Hidden" cuz the variables are like a, b, c, d, e etc.

Comment: It's minified code, not _hidden_.

Comment: yeah, but i still don't know if there's a way to find out how the request collects this data so that it can be sent later.

Answer (score 0):

[image: view payload source]

Open Dev-tools , Go to network tab and select the API call for which you want to see Payload source.
Then go to Payload tab in request details and click on "view source"
it will display payload source.

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for. When i click this "view-source" it doesn't show how/where it's made. It just shows the same but in 1 line and with "&" and "=" between the rest of things.

Comment: when you mean "how/where" do you means on the server the resource is issued from? I'm afraid that would not be possible. You could only acess this kind of information if script are on client side not server side (for security reason). You can only get that information if you have direct access on the server.